# multiple combo box in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am new to c#.
I am trying to create multiple combo boxes based on result from query. If the query results 5 items I need to make 5 combo boxes. But I do not know how to add event handler( on selection changed event).
I am using an array of combo boxes and number of boxes may vary. How do I come to know which comboBox of this array was changed and handle the event for same

Comment: In asp.net or in winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms...

As you are creating the controls, assign a generic event handler:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ADataTable)
{
    ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
    box.OnSelectionChanged += comboBox_OnSelectionChanged;
}

protected void comboBox_OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender;
        //do what you like with it
    }
}
```

In order to operate on the `ComboBox` in question, you need know nothing about the array.  In fact, you probably don't need the array at all unless there is more to the story.

Comment: This is a pretty good approach. I'd also recommend storing something (either the object or an index) to the `ComboBox.Tag` property to help identify 'which' one the `sender` is in the event handler.

Comment: @SiLo That was the point of my last sentence.  I'm not sure what the usefulness would be.  I would rather discard the arrays and just deal with the objects as I know them.

Answer (score 0):

you could either create a child class of the combo box in which case you can override the event, or you can get the name of your combobox and do something like so

```
comboboxName.OnSelected += (obj, args) => MethodToCall();
```

I dont think that is the exact name of the event but that should get you started. There are multiple variations of handling the event such as

```
comboboxName.OnSelected += MethodToCall;
void MethodToCall(Object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

or

```
comboboxName.OnSelected += () => delegate{/*put some code here*/};
```